# Named ranges with different lengths

Tags: excel

I have two named ranges, each one is a column (but I will have to turn them into arrays later), but with different lengths, lets say the first has a length of 5 and the second of 3. Let's say that the first is located in A1:A5, while the second in B1:B3.

In C1, I will put a value, 0 or 1. If it is 0, I want to have in column D the first range (the one in column A), while when in C1 I have 1, I want to have in column D the second range (the one in column B).

Is there a way to perform the task? thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by "have in column D the first (or second) range"? Have where in column D? Have what returned? A text string representing a range reference, e.g. "A1:A5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following formula in a range at least the size of your largest named range :

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(IF($C$1=0, "range1","range2")),ROW(D1))
```

Change `range1` and `range2` by your named range's names.

If the array are not of the same size you will get a #REF error, you can manage this by using `IfError({the formula}, "")`

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Also the Iferror fuction is very useful, I didn't know it, thanks!